# Attemp to index a nill value

Tags: lua, fivem

can anybody help me, please. I really don't know what to do... i tried everything,
Attemp to index a nill value (field, ?) at this line
`PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].messages = ChatMessages`

```
RegisterNetEvent('ttpPhone:client:UpdateMessages', function(ChatMessages, SenderNumber, New)
    local NumberKey = GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)
    print(NumberKey)

    if New then
        PhoneData.Chats[#PhoneData.Chats+1] = {
            name = IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber),
            number = SenderNumber,
            messages = {},
        }

        NumberKey = GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)

        PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey] = {
            name = IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber),
            number = SenderNumber,
            messages = ChatMessages
        }

        if PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread ~= nil then
            PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread = PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread + 1
            print(NumberKey)
        else
        print(NumberKey)
            PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread = 1
        end

        if PhoneData.isOpen then
            if SenderNumber ~= PhoneData.PlayerData.number then
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "PhoneNotification",
                    PhoneNotify = {
                        title = "Whatsapp",
                        text = "New message from "..IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber).."!",
                        icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
                        color = "#25D366",
                        timeout = 1500,
                    },
                })
            else
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "PhoneNotification",
                    PhoneNotify = {
                        title = "Whatsapp",
                        text = "Messaged yourself",
                        icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
                        color = "#25D366",
                        timeout = 4000,
                    },
                })
            end

            NumberKey = GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)
            ReorganizeChats(NumberKey)
            print(NumberKey)

            Wait(100)
            wrPhone.TriggerServerCallback('ttpPhone:server:GetContactPictures', function(Chats)
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "UpdateChat",
                    chatData = Chats[GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)],
                    chatNumber = SenderNumber,
                    Chats = Chats,
                })
            end,  PhoneData.Chats+1)
        else
        SendNUIMessage({
            action = "PhoneNotification",
            PhoneNotify = {
            title = "Whatsapp",
            text = "New message from "..IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber).."!",
            icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
            color = "#25D366",
            timeout = 3500,
            },
        })
            Config.PhoneApplications['whatsapp'].Alerts = Config.PhoneApplications['whatsapp'].Alerts + 1
            TriggerServerEvent('ttpPhone:server:SetPhoneAlerts', "whatsapp")
        end
    else
    print(chats)
    print(NumberKey)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------->       





PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].messages = ChatMessages            




<------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        if PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread ~= nil then
            PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread = PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread + 1
        else
            PhoneData.Chats[NumberKey].Unread = 1
        end

        if PhoneData.isOpen then
            if SenderNumber ~= PhoneData.PlayerData.number then
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "PhoneNotification",
                    PhoneNotify = {
                        title = "Whatsapp",
                        text = "New message from "..IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber).."!",
                        icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
                        color = "#25D366",
                        timeout = 1500,
                    },
                })
            else
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "PhoneNotification",
                    PhoneNotify = {
                        title = "Whatsapp",
                        text = "Messaged yourself",
                        icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
                        color = "#25D366",
                        timeout = 4000,
                    },
                })
            end

            NumberKey = GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)
            ReorganizeChats(NumberKey)

            Wait(100)
            wrPhone.TriggerServerCallback('ttpPhone:server:GetContactPictures', function(Chats)
                SendNUIMessage({
                    action = "UpdateChat",
                    chatData = Chats[GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)],
                    chatNumber = SenderNumber,
                    Chats = Chats,
                })
            end,  PhoneData.Chats)
        else
            SendNUIMessage({
                action = "PhoneNotification",
                PhoneNotify = {
                    title = "Whatsapp",
                    text = "New message from "..IsNumberInContacts(SenderNumber).."!",
                    icon = "fab fa-whatsapp",
                    color = "#25D366",
                    timeout = 3500,
                },
            })

            NumberKey = GetKeyByNumber(SenderNumber)
            ReorganizeChats(NumberKey)

            Config.PhoneApplications['whatsapp'].Alerts = Config.PhoneApplications['whatsapp'].Alerts + 1
            TriggerServerEvent('ttpPhone:server:SetPhoneAlerts', "whatsapp")
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dump the PhoneData table and check if the value exists, it probably doesn't and it's giving you nil.